# Is the word "strew" related to "straw?"

Tags: etymology

It seems to me that straw is in fact strewn. The ancient meaning of "strew" is "to lay flat." Anyway, they sound like related words.

I have noticed also that words in English which start with "str" tend to be words that relate to a protracted rather than an abrupt action.

Comment: They have the same [phonaestheme **str-**](https://davidappleyard.com/english/phonesthemic_initials.htm#str)

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul: thanks, it seems like the idea of being spread out in space or time is what I notices.

Comment: I've voted to close, as no research (with link/s // atributions) is included, but from the answers, this _could_ be a valid question. Research need only be basic etymologies.

Comment: Google `etymology strew`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a relation, as [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/straw) shows:

> apparently literally "that which is scattered or strewn," related to streowian (see strew)

About an ancient meaning of *lay flat* I'm not so sure, as the same source states:

> from PIE root *stere- "to spread."

Which would not be similar but not the same (I can lay flat a tree, but spreading it would be rather difficult)

About abrupt actions: how about   *strike*? I'm not sure you're on to anything there.

Comment: "strike" is indeed a striking counter-example. i think string, stretch, strew, stress, streak (even though fast, it still represents an action over time), struggle, strop, stream -- if there is another verb/noun that starts with "str" that is not a continuing/protracted thing, i would accept that maybe there is anything to it.

Comment: Strip, strap? There are more than 50 over [here](https://www.wordmom.com/verbs/that-start-with-str) and while quite some of them could be interpreted as protracted actions, it's by far not all and many action don't have to be protracted per se (strangling can be quite quick...)

Comment: strangling i think is consistent -- as a method of murder it is quite protracted versus a gunshot, etc. someone commented above and provided a link which seems consistent with my hypothesis. "strike" is an interesting exception.

Answer (score 1):

*Straw* and *strew* share the same phonaestheme ***str-***.
Phonaesthetics is the association of certain sounds with certain meanings.

The phonaestheme ***str-*** often conveys *narrowness* or *dispersion* or *spreading out in space*.

Examples: Straddle, strain, straw, strew, strap etc.

There's a whole slew of examples at [DavidAppleYard](https://davidappleyard.com/english/phonesthemic_initials.htm#str).

Comment: how do you feel about "strike", an except that (possibly monkey-owning) oerkelens so perceptively came up with?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the interesting and - to my knowledge - novel *protracted*/*abrupt* hypothesis I cannot see any evidence that it applies. Here are most of the "*str-*" verbs, with my own perceived *abrupt*/*protracted* classification. The proportions are about equal.

I don't claim this tentative classification to be correct. It is a merely a start and others may reasonably differ.

[image]

Comment: I disagree on at least some of these -- many classed as abrupt clearly are protracted -- straighten as in straighten up your room is clearly protracted. strop  take a long time, many strokes. strip like a strip tease is not abrupt. streak is quick but not abrupt -- there is in my mind a big difference between abrupt and quick. stride is an action that requires movement in space. i believe this is the first time a list like this has been created, btw.

Comment: @releseabe As I wrote, I do not claim accuracy and I welcome anyone's views on my tentative classification. I welcome your comment and have edited my answer to make it more open to others' opinions. I agree that the questioner has posed a novel concept. It will be good to see what other people think about it.

Comment: I understand but if the world is to better under "str" we need to discuss it. as with many word-related things, absolute clarity is illusive.

Comment: @Anton: English active verbs can be classified into durative and punctual. All durative verbs (the majority) take some time to happen (protracted): "read, live, visit, etc." Punctual verbs are rarer "Explode, start, break, fold, etc." these happen instantly (abrupt). All verbs are thus one or the other.The main difference is that in certain contexts punctual verbs cannot take the continuous form. https://www.ling.upenn.edu/Events/PLC/plc23/engelberg.html I am always cautious of patterns: correlation does not imply causation.

Comment: @Greybeard Agreed: *Post hoc ergo* not *propter hoc*, so to say. Durative/punctual is an interesting classification. From my viewpoint even *explode* is durative, as one can easily see in time lapse films of even nuclear explosions. I suppose some time frame must be defined if the classification is to work: nanoseconds for nuclear bomb, centiseconds for an athlete on the blocks; a few thousand years for a geological folding. Thank you.

Comment: @Anton The clue is in *...explode is durative, as one can easily see **in time lapse films*** - the point is that the verb developed by the way in which the action was originally perceived and "He lit a cigarette as the bomb **was exploding**" is not possible, whereas normally the continuous enables two distinct actions - . "He lit a cigarette as he **was reading** the report."